# Need to hide a views attachment when exposed filters are used

Tags: views

I have a view that displays employees and I've added an attachment that places the manager at the top of the page. I also have two exposed filters (department and name) that allow users to search the view. I'd like for the attachment to be hidden when the exposed filters are used. Any ideas? I've played with contextual filters but nothing has worked.

Comment: did you get it working ? Any feedback appreciated :)

Comment: My apologies. I'm not a developer so I don't know how to implement the code you provided. I was hoping for a setting in views or something from the admin. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't believe you'll find a UI solution. I added a step by step how-to. Just follow it.

Comment: Last, my answer assumes that your _attachment that places the manager at the top of the page_ is a view header

Answer (score 0):

I would try with [`hook_views_pre_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x)

```
function CUSTOM_MODULE_NAME_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME') {
    //inspect the url arguments 
    //hide the view header if your exposed fields are used
  }
}
```

Another maybe more straightforward solution would be to use [`template_preprocess_views_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/7.x-3.x)

```
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['view']->name == 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME') {
    if ($variables['view']->current_display == 'YOUR_DISPLAY_NAME' 
         && !empty($variables['exposed'])) {
      $variables['header'] = '';
    }
  }
}
```

For the 2nd one, this is a step by step how-to :

1. locate the folder of your current theme
2. open the file `template.php` in that folder with an editor
3. search in the code if there's already a function which name contains `preprocess_views_view`
4. if it does you'll place your code into that function, before the ending bracket `{`
5. if not, you'll create your own `template_preprocess_views_view` function, replacing `template` by the machine name of your theme, and write it at the bottom of the file :

   ```
   function your_theme_name_preprocess_views_view {
     //we'll place the code there
   }
   ```
6. open the related view and find its machine name in the url : ie for  `admin/structure/views/view/frontpage/edit/page` view, the view name is *frontpage* and the display name is *page*
7. in the following code, replace view_name and display name by yours :

   ```
     if ($variables['view']->name == 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME') {
       if ($variables['view']->current_display == 'YOUR_DISPLAY_NAME' 
            && !empty($variables['exposed'])) {
         $variables['header'] = '';
       }
     }
   ```
8. finally, put it all together, placing that code either inside the existing or in the new function, as seen above
9. Clear caches, or at least theme-registry cache

Hope you'll manage it, not that difficult

Comment: Did I mention this is Drupal 8? There is no template.php file in the theme. The only file I can find by that name is in the vendor/twig/twig/lib/twig directory.

Comment: Nope. Then locate `YOURTHEME.theme` in your theme dir

Answer (score 0):

The preprocess method shown previously doesn't work as intended in Drupal 7. It's a great start, but the function hides the header/attachment if an exposed filter itself is present, not if one is actively being used. The code below will hide the attachment (in this case attachment_before) when the exposed filter is used.

```
function MYTHEME_core_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['view']->name == 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME') {
    if ($variables['view']->current_display == 'YOUR_DISPLAY_NAME'
         && !empty($variables['view']->exposed_input['YOUR_FILTER']['value'])) {
      $variables['attachment_before'] = '';
    }
  }
}
```